# Prevent SDKs from clearing the shared WebView cache

Tags: android, caching, webview

I'm building a WebView-based Android app that relies on the WebView browser cache for performance.

I'm also using some third-party SDKs that render their own WebView instances.

When a third-party SDK calls `WebView.clearCache()`, [it clears the cache for the entire app, including my WebView instance.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#clearCache(boolean))

Is there a way to prevent this behavior by isolating my WebView's cache or intercepting calls to `clearCache()`?